# How to make a character bounce when a certain object is touched

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity trying to create a platform game. I've tried various scripts trying to make my character bounce when touching a certain kind of object. When a certain button is pressed, I want this effect to stop. Do you know any way to make it bounce back up when it lands on a platform? Should I make my character a rigidbody?

Thank you for your patience and consideration.

Comment: How do you detect touching, using collider?

Comment: @Johnny Yes, I use colliders for detecting when the caracter hits a platform, but I can't make it bounce and can't stop it when a button is pressed

Comment: Could you detect when button is pressed in general? If so, just attach tag to your character, find it in scene by tag and start attached animation...(the same story for stop)

Comment: @Johnny Yes, the connection works, I don't know how to add the bouncing feature

Comment: You should create animation and attach it to the animator component of your player. By the way you explained you should have looping animation which you can control using triggers...So when start button is pressed you set start trigger when stop button is set you set stop trigger...

Comment: @Johnny Could you help me with the two functions please? Do you have some sample code?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any code here. You could look at some tutorial to have feeling https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuqPRj-Fjbs or https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html. Not sure if you look at that one already. About bouncing feature it is actually just changing position of the object across the time...